# Writing an if statement in R to find multiples of 4 or 7 but it keeps returning true for somethings thats false

Tags: r

I am writing an if statement comparing multiples of 4 or 7, pretty basic stuff but I am a novice programmer. Below is the function and if statements, and whenever I test 55 it returns true for some reason even though 55 is not a multiple of 4 or 7. Why is this happening? Any help appreciated, thank you so much!

```
isPostiveMultipleOf4Or7 <- function(n) {
    if(is.character(n)) {
        return(FALSE)
    }
    if(is.logical(n)){
        return(FALSE)
    }
    if(abs(n)%%4 | abs(n)%%7 == 0){
        return(TRUE)
    } 
    if(abs(n)%%4 | abs(n)%%7 != 0){
        return(FALSE)
    
    }

}
        
55%%7 == 0
test_isPostiveMultipleOf4Or7()
isPostiveMultipleOf4Or7("hello")
isPostiveMultipleOf4Or7(28)
isPostiveMultipleOf4Or7(55)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to have the `== 0` and `!= 0` on both sides of `|`. It is returning `TRUE` since `abs(n)%%4` returns a value.

```
isPostiveMultipleOf4Or7 <- function(n) {
  if(is.character(n)) {
    return(FALSE)
  }
  if(is.logical(n)){
    return(FALSE)
  }
  if(abs(n)%%4 == 0 | abs(n)%%7 == 0){
    return(TRUE)
  }
  if(abs(n)%%4 != 0 | abs(n)%%7 != 0){
    return(FALSE)

  }
}
```

**Test**

```
isPostiveMultipleOf4Or7("hello")
#[1] FALSE

isPostiveMultipleOf4Or7(28)
#[1] TRUE

isPostiveMultipleOf4Or7(55)
#[1] FALSE
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and quick response, super appreciated!!